# How to store an image using NSData in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, file, screen-scraping, uiimage, nsdata

How do I take a UIImage and store it preferably as NSData (to write to a file)?  Is there some obvious method out there, or could someone provide a code snippet?

Thanks in advance!

PS. My next question will probably be for a code snippet to capture the current screen image.  The snippets I've seen so far appear to be serious overkill for what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can serialize a UIImage using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`.

Comment: Thanks Dave!  I crossed paths with those earlier but mistook them as being something else; would never have revisited them if you didn't point them out again.  Code working - very pleased!